# Random number Game

Tags: java

I am trying to create a random number game where the users give a lower and upper number, the program asks how many guesses he/she wants then goes on to guess the number.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a low number: ");
    int min = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a high number: ");
    int max = s.nextInt();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    System.out.print("The Random Number is " + value);
```

This finds a random value between the given values i think i need a for loop for the guesses but finding out how to do it is becoming difficult any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines before your current code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of guesses: ");
int count = s.nextInt();
```

Afterwards, put your code inside a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
  System.out.print("Enter a low number: ");
  int min = s.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter a high number: ");
  int max = s.nextInt();
  Random rand = new Random();
  int value = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  System.out.print("The Random Number is " + value);
}
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly! The program must also ask the user for their guess, if they guessed right then the program would tell them how many guesses they did it in and if failed how many they failed in

Comment: It that case you have to create the random number before the loop and alter the loop to quit if the numbers (input and random) match. Nevertheless, you implement a counter so that you can tell the user how many tries he needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it in this way :-

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a low number: ");
            int min = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter a high number: ");
            int max = s.nextInt();
            Random rand = new Random();
            System.out.println("Enter no of guesses : ");
            int noOfGuesses = s.nextInt();

            for(int i=0; i < noOfGuesses; i++){
                int value = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                System.out.print("\nThe Random Number is " + value);
            }

Here is the output :- Enter a low number: 5
Enter a high number: 50
Enter no of guesses : 
5

The Random Number is 45
The Random Number is 42
The Random Number is 40
The Random Number is 9
The Random Number is 12
```

Comment: The random numbers cant be printed, the user is to guess the random number between the values given at the start